# Power supply multivibrator relay dc motor

Tags: power-supply, power

Dear friends I m nwcomer. A typical prblm in my project i m facing.....9v dc supply,555 astbl multivbrtr ,relay & dc motor r cnectd to run motor in astble mode.at no load condition evrythng is okk. When v apply load to motor voltage drops and relay cnt operate.plz tell me solution.6v relay with 100ohm/1watt resistor is used in series wth relay coil which also protects base of transistor547..if I use 12v supply then prblm gets solved but relay can't denrgise back due to excessive magnetic field.how can i solve prblm with using same power supply for multivibrator,relay and dc motor.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Hi! A warm welcome from my side, too. For me, English isn't my first language, and I think it is not for you either. That makes writing correctly harder. However, you seem to be randomly omitting letters from words. I don't know why. Please don't do that, it makes your text so hard to read that I have no understanding of what you're asking. Generally, your browser (even on your phone!) has a spell-check engine. Use that! "Prblm" is not a word, and correcting such simple mistakes makes your question much easier to read and hence, to answer.

Comment: As v hv habit to type short words in whatsapp so I m using st mthd

Comment: Welcome, Ilyas!  A question in standard English, accompanied by a schematic, would  make the job of providing an answer that much easier. It would also eliminate the added burden of deciphering a detailed description using shortened words.

Answer (score 0):

A 555 astable could be used to control a DC motor in two ways as follows:

1. Alternately run and stop the motor using a low astable frequency.
2. Vary the motor speed through PWM control.

For the first, a relay driven by the 555 output would suffice to switch on/switch off the motor.

For the second, a power transistor would be required for PWM control of the motor.

Your problem stems primarily from a mismatch between rated voltage/current and that required.

You have a 9V supply, driving a 6V relay to control a ?V DC motor. The right way would be for all of them to have the same voltage rating.

The power supply current rating should be adequate to start and run the motor. Likewise with the driver output current.

The motor stall and relay drop out would have been caused by a power supply overload.

Comment: Well explained in brief.with 6v relay I hv 100ohm /1watt resistor in series with 547npn tr to limit current.previously I had used 9v relay but after facing v drop I took 6v relay,but prblm couldn't be solved.my adapter is of 9v/1amp.should I use 9v/2amp adapter?or it may be due lasting of motor becoz I hv been running since 6 mnths.

Comment: Hi Ilyas, You have not furnished a schematic, without which, it would be difficult to address your problems.